# on server IIS input string not in correct format with date and time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net MVC application .NET application . I get error input

string not in correct format with date and time  when publish application

over IIS but on local machine not get any error

I search for that I found that error on datetime on the line below

```
if (Session[SessionKeys.VisaExpiryDate] == null)
{
    visaExpiryDate = 0;
}
else
{
   DateTime visDateExpire = Convert.ToDateTime(Session[SessionKeys.VisaExpiryDate]);
    visaExpiryDate = JulianDate.DateTimeToJulian(visDateExpire);

}
```

for details function as below :

```
public static int DateTimeToJulian(DateTime dateTime)
  {
      string szDate = string.Empty;
      int nPrefix = 0;
      int nSufix = 0;

      nPrefix = (Convert.ToInt32(dateTime.Year.ToString().Substring(1, 1) + "00") + 100) + Convert.ToInt32(dateTime.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2));

      nSufix = dateTime.DayOfYear;
      szDate = nPrefix.ToString() + nSufix.ToString("000");

      if (szDate.Length > 6)
          szDate = szDate.Substring(1, 6);

      return Convert.ToInt32(szDate);
  }
```

error say input string not in correct format with datetime

so How to solve this error to work on server ?

Comment: In your previous question it was pointed out to you that there is [built in support for the Julian calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.juliancalendar?view=net-7.0) - why are you not using that?